# Property does not exist on type - redux-thunk await dispatch

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have this exact issue described here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/485#issuecomment-610654378

so I imported ThunkDispatch directly and am using that. I can't get any keys from the response of dispatch without it throwing `property does not exist` error

```
@reduxjs/toolkit@1.5.1
```

```
const response = await dispatch(deactivateSubscription(args))
```

```
const response: PayloadAction<ApiResponse<EmptyBodyResponse>, string, {
    arg: DeactivateSubscriptionArgs;
    requestId: string;
    requestStatus: "fulfilled";
}, never> | PayloadAction<...>
```

```
export interface ApiResponse<T = unknown> {
  body: T
  error: Error
  success: boolean
  message?: string
}
```

```
TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'PayloadAction<ApiResponse<EmptyBodyResponse>, string, { arg: DeactivateSubscriptionArgs; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<...>'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'PayloadAction<ApiResponse<EmptyBodyResponse>, string, { arg: DeactivateSubscriptionArgs; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never>'.
    149 |
  > 150 |                     if (!response.error) {
        |                                   ^^^^^
    151 |                       setIsEditing(false)
    152 |                     }
    153 |                   }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the `createAsyncThunk` docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), `createAsyncThunk` does not return the actual "response". Instead, it returns the "final action object that was dispatched", in order to avoid "uncaught rejected Promise" errors in your code.

You can [unwrap the result action](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions) to get the actual data back in the component.

Also, make sure that [you are using a `Dispatch` type that correctly understands thunks](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#standard-redux-toolkit-project-setup-with-typescript).

Comment: Sure. Note that in an upcoming RTK release, we will provide a `.unwrap()` method directly on the returned promise: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/775#issuecomment-801143225